# Prove that $a,b,c$ are the sides of a triangle

Tags: linear-algebra, contest-math, triangles

> $a,b,c\in\mathbb R_{>0}$ are such that
>   $$\begin{cases}a^2x+b^2y+c^2z=1\\xy+yz+zx=1\end{cases}$$
>   has a unique solution $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^{3}$. Prove that $a,b,c$ are the sides of a triangle.

This is a selection to IMO problem. I have no helpful observations so far. Perhaps someone could give me a hint?

Only two people got almost the maximum of points for this problem.

Comment: Presumably, $a^2x$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Edited, sorry.

Comment: The first equation is that of a plane, the second that of a two-sheeted hyperboloid. The solution is unique when the plane tangents the hyperboloid, so that you can express the colinearity of the normals$$\frac{a^2}{y+z}=\frac{b^2}{z+x}=\frac{c^2}{x+y}.$$
Solving for $a^2,b^2,c^2$, this gives
$$a^2=\frac12(y+z)\\b^2=\frac12(z+x)\\c^2=\frac12(x+y).$$